# Lightbox for embeddable JavaScript widget? Like Feedback tabs for UserVoice/GetSatisfaction

Tags: javascript, widget, lightbox

There are so many lightboxes to choose from, I'm looking for a very lightweight one to use in an embedded javascript widget that would be used on a number of different web sites.  This would work in a similar way to the GetSatisfaction/UserVoice feedback tab.

Here are the requirements for the lightbox:

- Very small javascript download (animation not needed)
- Self contained, not dependent on any libraries such as jquery, etc.
- Works in major browsers
- Lightbox displays HTML content from a given URL
- Close button (like GetSatisfaction or UserVoice)
- Dims background
- Avoids javascript namespace conflicts (or can easily be made to avoid them)
- CSS styling of lightbox does not interfere with site styling

Have you used an existing lightbox scripts for this same purpose with similar requirements?  Did you roll your own?  Insights welcome!

Thanks,

Eliot

Comment: Answer (link to tutorial) to a similar question on how to create a JavaScript widget is insightful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428840/how-do-hosted-services-like-uservoice-embed-their-content-on-other-web-sites/6045355#6045355

Answer (score 0):

So far I found this.... which is not exactly what I am looking for... but you might like it...
[domainfunk.com/jquery-feedback-tab](http://domainfunk.com/jquery-feedback-tab)